# Merge DATASET1 and DATASET2 files

Tags: sas

dataset1

```
Fuel    NOx
Ethanol 3.741
Ethanol 2.295
Ethanol 1.498
Ethanol 2.881
Ethanol 0.76
Ethanol 3.12
Ethanol 0.638
Ethanol 1.17
Ethanol 2.358
Ethanol 0.606
Ethanol 3.669
Ethanol 1
Ethanol 0.981
Ethanol 1.192
Ethanol 0.926
Ethanol 1.59
Ethanol 1.806
Ethanol 1.962
Ethanol 4.028
Ethanol 3.148
Ethanol 1.836
Ethanol 2.845
Ethanol 1.013
Ethanol 0.414
Ethanol 0.812
Ethanol 0.374
Ethanol 3.623
Ethanol 1.869
Ethanol 2.836
Ethanol 3.567
Ethanol 0.866
Ethanol 1.369
Ethanol 0.542
Ethanol 2.739
Ethanol 1.2
Ethanol 1.719
Ethanol 3.423
Ethanol 1.634
Ethanol 1.021
Ethanol 2.157
Ethanol 3.361
Ethanol 1.39
Ethanol 1.947
Ethanol 0.962
Ethanol 0.571
Ethanol 2.219
Ethanol 1.419
Ethanol 3.519
Ethanol 1.732
Ethanol 3.206
Ethanol 2.471
Ethanol 1.777
Ethanol 2.571
Ethanol 3.952
Ethanol 3.931
Ethanol 1.587
Ethanol 1.397
Ethanol 3.536
Ethanol 2.202
Ethanol 0.756
Indolene    4.818
Indolene    2.849
Indolene    3.275
Indolene    4.691
Indolene    4.255
Indolene    5.064
Indolene    2.118
Indolene    4.602
Indolene    2.286
Indolene    0.97
Indolene    3.965
Indolene    5.344
Indolene    3.834
Ethanol 1.62
Ethanol 3.656
Ethanol 2.964
82rongas    6.021
82rongas    4.467
82rongas    3.046
82rongas    1.596
82rongas    0.835
82rongas    5.498
82rongas    5.47
82rongas    4.084
82rongas    0.716
94%Eth  2.382
94%Eth  1.004
94%Eth  0.623
94%Eth  1.03
94%Eth  2.593
94%Eth  2.699
94%Eth  3.177
94%Eth  1.151
94%Eth  0.474
94%Eth  2.814
94%Eth  3.308
94%Eth  3.031
94%Eth  2.537
94%Eth  2.403
94%Eth  2.412
```

dataset2

```
Fuel    FuelCD 
Gasohol F4
Methanol    F2
Ethanol F5
94%Eth  F6
82rongas    F1
Indolene    F3
```

```
Fuel    FuelCD  NOx
Gasohol F4  
Methanol    F2  
Ethanol F5  
94%Eth  F6  
82rongas    F1  
Indolene    F3  
Ethanol     3.741
Ethanol     2.295
Ethanol     1.498
Ethanol     2.881
Ethanol     0.76
Ethanol     3.12
Ethanol     0.638
Ethanol     1.17
Ethanol     2.358
Ethanol     0.606
Ethanol     3.669
Ethanol     1
Ethanol     0.981
Ethanol     1.192
Ethanol     0.926
Ethanol     1.59
Ethanol     1.806
Ethanol     1.962
Ethanol     4.028
Ethanol     3.148
Ethanol     1.836
Ethanol     2.845
Ethanol     1.013
Ethanol     0.414
Ethanol     0.812
Ethanol     0.374
Ethanol     3.623
Ethanol     1.869
Ethanol     2.836
Ethanol     3.567
Ethanol     0.866
Ethanol     1.369
Ethanol     0.542
Ethanol     2.739
Ethanol     1.2
Ethanol     1.719
Ethanol     3.423
Ethanol     1.634
Ethanol     1.021
Ethanol     2.157
Ethanol     3.361
Ethanol     1.39
Ethanol     1.947
Ethanol     0.962
Ethanol     0.571
Ethanol     2.219
Ethanol     1.419
Ethanol     3.519
Ethanol     1.732
Ethanol     3.206
Ethanol     2.471
Ethanol     1.777
Ethanol     2.571
Ethanol     3.952
Ethanol     3.931
Ethanol     1.587
Ethanol     1.397
Ethanol     3.536
Ethanol     2.202
Ethanol     0.756
Indolene        4.818
Indolene        2.849
Indolene        3.275
Indolene        4.691
Indolene        4.255
Indolene        5.064
Indolene        2.118
Indolene        4.602
Indolene        2.286
Indolene        0.97
Indolene        3.965
Indolene        5.344
Indolene        3.834
Ethanol     1.62
Ethanol     3.656
Ethanol     2.964
82rongas        6.021
82rongas        4.467
82rongas        3.046
82rongas        1.596
82rongas        0.835
82rongas        5.498
82rongas        5.47
82rongas        4.084
82rongas        0.716
94%Eth      2.382
94%Eth      1.004
94%Eth      0.623
94%Eth      1.03
94%Eth      2.593
94%Eth      2.699
94%Eth      3.177
94%Eth      1.151
94%Eth      0.474
94%Eth      2.814
94%Eth      3.308
94%Eth      3.031
94%Eth      2.537
94%Eth      2.403
94%Eth      2.412
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you please clean up this to illustrate your data more cleanly and a smaller sample would be helpful. Also please include anything you've tried and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in the question. Just MERGE the two datasets.  Make sure they are both sorted by the BY variable first.

```
data want;
  merge dataset1 dataset2 ;
  by fuel;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data sets and do `MERGE one two; BY fuel;`

Example:

```
proc sort data=one;
  by fuel;
proc sort data=two;
  by fuel;
data want;
  merge one two;
  by fuel;
run;
```

Alternatively, you can use SQL to merge data sets.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    coalesce(one.fuel, two.fuel) as fuel
  , one.NOx, two.fuelcd
  from one
  full join two
  on one.fuel = two.fuel
  ;
```